# How to do a clean install of ubuntu on a GPT disk while keeping the partition table?

Tags: gpt

Is there anyway to do it? I tried first using gdisk on my old partition table (mbr) then using liveCD to do a clean (and encrypted) installation. After that I ended up with a MBR again. I don't mind having to wipe out my disk (again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the something else option, select "use this volume for encryption" (or something like that) on the partition manager.

Answer (score 0):

If the disk has no existing partitions, the installer might be creating a fresh and new partition table; but it should not do that if the disk has existing partitions and if you tell the installer to use the (badly named) "something else" setup option, which requires you to set up your partitions manually. Thus, you might consider setting up your partitions ahead of time and using the "something else" option to assign them mount points and filesystem types.

Comment: Here's what I did: I bought a new sony s series, used a live CD and gdisk to create a UEFI partition, double click the installer, chose option to wipe my win7 installation, and install an encrypted installation, and ended up with a MBR partition table again. I also want to dual boot encrypted Ubuntu with windows on a GPT disk. Any help?

Comment: As I said, use the "something else" option rather than one of the auto-partitioning options. Also, on a new computer you should be able to use your computer's boot manager to specify an EFI-mode boot of the installer rather than a BIOS-mode boot. The former should result in use of GPT by default.

Comment: The "something else" option is not present for the encrypted installation. If i'm wrong, please point me to it.